# Django: show different list based on 'a' tag click

Tags: python, django

In my Django website I'd like the user to be able to choose to show two different lists, one at a time but on the same page, based on the click of the user on a 'a' tag? Hope someone could help! If it isn't possible to do so, is there a different way I can achieve it? I really don't know what should I change. Thanks a lot!

views.py

```
class searchesView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search/searches.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('FORM POSTED WITH {}'.format(request.POST['srh']))
        srch = request.POST.get('srh')
        if srch:
            sr = Info.objects.filter(Q(band__icontains=srch))
            sd = Info.objects.filter(Q(disco__icontains=srch))
            sp = Info.objects.filter(Q(band__icontains=srch) & Q(disco__icontains=srch))

            #if sr.exists() and sd.exists():
                #return render(self.request, 'search/searches.html')


        #else:
            paginator = Paginator(sr, 10)
            page_number = request.GET.get('page')
            page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

            return render(self.request, 'search/searches.html', {'sr':sr,
                                                                       'sd': sd, 'sp':sp,
                                                                       'page_obj': page_obj
                                                                       })

        else:
            return render(self.request, 'search/searches.html')
```

template:

```
    {% if sp %}
    <a href="{%url 'searches' sd%}" >Band: {{ request.POST.srh }}</a><br/>
    <a href="{%url 'searches'%}" >Album: {{ request.POST.srh }}</a>
    {% else %}

    {% if sd %}
    {% for y in sd %}
    <div class="container">

      <div class="album">

        {%if y.cover%}
        <img src= "{{y.cover.url}}" width="100%">
        {%endif%}
      </div>

      <div class="info">
        <table class="talbum" style="height:400px">
          <tr><th colspan="2"><h2>{{y.disco}}</h2></th></tr>
          <tr><td> Band: </td><td> {{y.band}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Anno: </td><td> {{y.anno}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Disco: </td><td> {{y.disco}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Etichetta: </td><td> {{y.etichetta_d}} </td></tr>
          <tr><td> Matrice: </td><td> {{y.matrice}} </td></tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
    {%else%}


{% if sr %}
{% for k in sr %}
<div class="container_band">
  <div class=album_band>
    <!-- insert an image -->
    {%if k.cover%}
    <img src= "{{k.cover.url}}" width="100%">
    {%endif%}
  </div>

  <div class="info_band">
    <!-- insert table info -->
    <table>
      <tr><th><h2>{{k.band}}</h2></th></tr>
      <tr><td> Anno: </td><td> {{k.anno}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Disco: </td><td> {{k.disco}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Etichetta: </td><td> {{k.etichetta_d}} </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Matrice: </td><td> {{k.matrice}} </td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
{%endfor%}


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>



{% else %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="message">
    No results for "{{ request.POST.srh }}"
  </div>
  <div class="immagine"
  </div>
</div>

{%endif%}
{%endif%}
{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well displaying and changing frontend behaviour lays in JavaScript kingdom. To achieve what you want you you should define a wrapper around the content you want to toggle (hide/show) and give it an html id. To make is as simple as possible use jQuery [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/). To achieve what you want it would be better not to use 'a' tag because clicking it would tak you to different site you can use 'button' instead. so a quick instruction with example:

1. Define two elements you want to hide/show depending on some action (form or table whatever)
2. Wrap each of the elements in a wrapper div and give them id's

```
<div id="table"> whole table content </div>
<div> id="other_table"> another table content </div>
```

3. define a button and give it some id

```
<button id="btn_toggle">On click toggle tables</button>
```

4. In the template define script like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // one of tables will be hidden on default
   $("#other_table").hide();
   $("#btn_toggle").click( function() {
      $("#other_table").toggle();
      $("#table").toggle();
    }

});
```

If you need more information just ask. Don't forget to include jQuery in the template

Comment: Great! I'll take a look at JQuery, Thanks!